# Error in writeOGR when trying to export spatial polygons as shapefile in R

Tags: shapefile, r, polygon, sp, rgdal

I am trying to export polygons that i have created for home range data but when i go to export them get this error message:

```
Error in writeOGR(colkud95[1, ], ".", "colonyhomerange", driver = "ESRI Shapefile") : 
  Spatial Polygons objects should have valid ordering comments
use rgeos::createSPComment()
```

```
# main package for this analysis
library(adehabitatHR)  
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

tracks.utm <- dput(new("SpatialPointsDataFrame", data = structure(list(TripID = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Breeding stage` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), coords.nrs = 1:2, coords = structure(c(174.78327, 
174.78326, 174.78332, 174.78323, 174.78325, 174.78277, 174.78238, 
174.78238, 174.78244, 174.78278, -41.09482, -41.09491, -41.09484, 
-41.09491, -41.09496, -41.09564, -41.09637, -41.09685, -41.09747, 
-41.09771), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", 
"y"))), bbox = structure(c(174.78238, -41.09771, 174.78332, -41.09482
), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), c("min", "max"
))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
projargs = "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs")))

# Organising variable 1 refers to Trip ID
colkud<-kernelUD(tracks.utm[,1],h="href", 
                 grid=1000,same4all=T)

# Organising variable 2 refers to Breeding stage
colkudb<-kernelUD(tracks.utm[,2],h="href", 
                  grid=1000,same4all=T)

kernel.area(colkud,percent=50)
kernel.area(colkudb,percent=50)
kernel.area(colkud,percent=95)
kernel.area(colkudb,percent=95)

colkud95<- getverticeshr(colkud, percent=95)
colkud50<- getverticeshr(colkud, percent=50)
colkud95b<- getverticeshr(colkudb, percent=95)
colkud50b<- getverticeshr(colkudb, percent=50)

# This is where the error occurs
writeOGR(colkud95,".",layer="colkud95",driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

I haven't had any luck searching for an answer to this, my aim is to create polygons for home range and then export them as a shapefile to be used in QGIS.

Comment: You should try and make this a bit more reproducible. You've given us a sample of what I guess is `HRtracks` but then switch to `tracks.utm` which I guess is a transformed version of `HRtracks`? If you can add the transform line and get rid of as many irrelevant lines as possible, ie anything that doesn't contribute to constructing `colkud95`, that would make this a bit cleaner, leaner, and clearer - the fewer lines of code people think they have to run, the *more* likely they are to help!

Comment: I've just tried the example given in the help for `getverticeshr` and it works, so its more likely to be something dependent on your data.

Comment: Please note that your dput object was incorrect. This is the second time that I fixed the same object in one of your posts. If you continue to use this object in creating a reproducible example, please use these changes so that you have a resulting object for use in the example. We I edited your post, I also removed spurious code ie., removed reference to `HRtracks` since you never use the object and we do not have access to the data.

Answer (score 2):

First, check that you have a valid object to export to a shapefile in the first place. Your example is not reproducible and returns an error:

> The grid is too small to allow the estimation of home-range

As I recall, depending on how the functions are parametrized, it is possible for `adehabitatHR::getverticeshr` to return a SpatialPolygons object, which lacks attributes and do not reflect the output in the functions example. You can check output using `class(colkud95)`. For writing a shapefile, you are after a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, if the object is a `SpatialPolygons` type you will need to convert it to an exportable object.

If you have a spatial object with attributes, I highly recommend using `sf`, as opposed to `rgdal`, to write the shapefile. It is faster and the syntax is a bit easier. You will have to coerce your sp object to sf but, that is easily done on the fly using `as`. The function `st_write` parses the correct format based on the file extension.

```
sf::st_write(as(colkud95, "sf"), "out_shpfile.shp")
```

Please note that if I increase the grid size to 2500, I can get your example to run but, the largest volume contour I can produce is 75%, which I find odd because if it can create a KDE it should be able to return all of the volume contours for the density estimate. The output is, in fact, a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object. So, you really need to look closely at your output(s) as there is likely something invalid.

```
colkud <- kernelUD(tracks.utm[,1],h="href", grid=2500, 
                   same4all=TRUE)
  kernel.area(colkud, percent=50)
  kernel.area(colkud, percent=75)
  colkud50<- getverticeshr(colkud, percent=50)
  colkud75 <- getverticeshr(colkud, percent=75)
```

Here is a workaround using the raster class and directly calculating the percent volume(s) using `spatialEco::raster.vol`. In this example, we use `adehabitatHR::estUDm2spixdf` to create a KDE raster of an individual animal, calculate the 75% volume contour then, plot the result to compare with the result from `adehabitatHR::kernel.area` and `adehabitatHR::getverticeshr`. You can convert each raster volume contour to a polygon and then export to shapefiles.

```
library(raster)
library(spatialEco)

colkud.kde <- raster(adehabitatHR::estUDm2spixdf(colkud))
  kde75 <- raster.vol(colkud.kde, p = 0.75)
  colkud75 <- getverticeshr(colkud, percent=75)
    plot(kde75)
      plot(colkud75, add=TRUE)
```